# Where is my girlfriend?

Tags: visual, cipher, rubiks-cube

*Well, I'm really, really sorry to everyone who has spent time trying to tackle this puzzle. I made a HUGE mistake in the presentation. I honestly don't know how I managed to make a mistake this big, but in any case, I'm sorry to have wasted your time. What's worse is that I didn't even realize the mistake I had made and I posted comments encouraging people and telling them that they were on the right track.*

*The rubik's cube image is wrong. I don't really have an excuse, but this is what happened: during the development of this puzzle, I toyed with several different ways to incorporate the rubik's cube. One of the versions of the puzzle involved the rubik's cube image that I ended up using, but it isn't the one that matches the cipher text that I provided.*

*The correct image should feature a solved rubik's cube net numbered in the following fashion.*

```
         [ 1][ 2]
         [ 3][ 4]

[ 5][ 6] [ 7][ 8] [ 9][10]
[11][12] [13][14] [15][16]

         [17][18]
         [19][20]

         [21][22]
         [23][24]
```

*and the exact same unsolved rubik's cube, with no letters on it, and every square marked with it's appropriate number.*

*Again, I'm* **really, really** *sorry to have wasted people's time. This isn't quite the impression I had intended to make for my debut question on the site. I'm going to flag this question for closure as "off-topic," but I'm not sure that that is the correct course of action.*

The intended solution is:

> permute each block of the cipher text the same way that the cube squares are permuted

and then

> Use the substitution defined by mapping the "in order" alphabet above the board to the first line of the cipher text.

---

---

My girlfriend teaches the third grade at a nearby elementary school. Today, I was supposed to meet her in her classroom after the school day ended, so we could go to the movies together.

However, when I got to her classroom, I couldn't find her. Instead,this message was printed on the white board:

```
vmrdtonhilxwagfsecjkbupq
oowaoijhbhjxcdbrrccbsjdo
jwoiyaljrtjccmpgdtpxalcr
```

On her desk, there was a 2x2x2 rubik's cube with some writing on it. I'm not sure if it is important, but I've reproduced the net of the cube as I found it, as well as the net of the solved state.

Solved Cube: [image: Solved Cube]

Her Cube, as found: [image: Updated Cube]

It appears that she had written the lettering on herself.

A final detail in the room struck me as out of place. Above the white board, there were cards displaying the cursive alphabet, e.g. `Aa, Bb, Cc...`, however it appeared that the final letters `Yy` and `Zz` were missing.

All in all, the board looked something like this:

[image: Me looking at board]

Can you help me decipher the message on the board?

*Edit: I modified her cube so that one of two logical orderings is forced. This does not change the answer, but reduces the trial and error to find it.*

*I also added another image which might be helpful.*

Hint:

> Permutation(s) are involved (pretty obvious because of the rubik's cube.), but just permutations will not solve this.

Bigger hint:

> The first line of cipher text is not actually part of the message! It is there to help you decipher the following two lines.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling! This a great puzzle for a new user!

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Thanks. Lurking pays off eventually.

Comment: Woah that is a big edit...

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Yeah. I realized that there was a non trivial amount of trial and error that might be necessary. I'm hoping to reduce that. Again, the answer is unchanged, but this will hopefully make things a bit easier. I had originally intended for this puzzle to be almost entirely visual, but my computer drawing skills are lacking.

Comment: Okay, well I'm up to the cipher, but can't find a way to get anything non gibberish

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I added some hints. I spend most of my time over at ppcg and I really wish there was a sandbox here so that I could have ironed out this puzzle first (I grant that sandboxes don't make as much sense here as they do on ppcg though).

Comment: @liam well sandbox did exist here and not a long time ago too. But not for ciphers..

Comment: I'm sorry to say mate, but I don't think she wants to be found :(

Comment: She really doesn't want to go to the movies, does she?

Comment: That's not the right colors for a rubiks cube!

Comment: Do you think you can fix this puzzle rather than closing it?  If so, I'd suggest doing that (by replacing the erroneous images with the correct ones).  Seems like some solvers were on their way to figuring it out.

Comment: @DanRussell is that an okay thing to do? It would basically just wipe out all the answers posted. I'm not sure what the policy is for that.

Comment: Yes, I think so.  Just change the whole header of your question to say something like "This puzzle has changed substantially from the original post due to an error." I assume @BeastlyGerbil and others will adjust their answers to fit the correct version of the puzzle.

Comment: Whenever I make some puzzle and post it online I panic every day and double check the entire thing just to make sure.

Comment: Well... this may look like a job for... @codewarrior0!

Answer (score 6):

If we solve the cube with the writing on it we get:

> [image]

This suggest that each section is a letter in the alphabet, Liam has said also said the alphabet goes in a snaking pattern:

> [image]

And the pattern:

> [image]

This is why Y and Z cards are missing, there are only 24 squares

This also means you girlfriend's cube looks like this:

> [image]

Now the cipher...

**We know it can't just be from the cubes** because there is a 'y' in the cipher but obviously not in the cubes, (also translating just gives gibberish)

Comment: This is correct and a necessary step.

Comment: @Liam I have the next bit just writing it up...

Comment: Interesting, to observe that "K,.,M,N,O" are in the natural order. So one would guess the place of the letter L instantly. Although I have no clue what this would mean, if anything.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I'm going to give you a hint because this is my fault. In hindsight I should have made this clearer. The ordering should be snaking AB and then next line DC, etc. I should have added letters on different lines to force a single valid ordering.

Comment: @Liam oops, so I have it the wrong way round?

Comment: aaaah! I was right the first time lol.... i thought it was snaking, then i changed halfway after seeing beastly's answer lol... back to 0 again XD

Comment: You had every other line correct. (and now you still have every other correct, but you've switched which were right and which were wrong). I'm going to make a quick edit to the question to fix this, because this is my fault.

Comment: @Liam fixed it now, and I think I have lead on the next bit...

Comment: Well either i messed up or I was wrong... I tried replacing every letters with the corresponding one and vice versa but both only gave me jibberish.

Comment: @stackreader, added the original cube, but like you said it is gibberish

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is wondering, it says:

> dear liam i ran to the bathroom please do not touch my stuff

OP gave away the solve path. What went wrong was that the letter cues in the "Her Cube" image were incorrect, and led solvers to use an incorrect reading order for deriving the permutation.

The correct permutation is derived like so:

1. Write the alphabet onto the solved, flattened Rubik's cube in normal reading order (left to right, then top to bottom)
2. "Unsolve" the cube to get it into the color configuration shown in "Her Cube". Ignore the letter cues.
3. Flatten the cube again and read the permuted alphabet off of the cube in normal reading order.

The letters on each completed image should look like this:

```
  AB
  CD
EFGHIJ
KLMNOP        "Solved"
  QR
  ST
  UV
  WX

  
  KC
  EH 
SAWIDF 
NLMPVB        "Her Cube"
  QT
  OJ 
  RX
  UG
```

This permutation key is used to reorder all three lines on the blackboard:

```
P. Key:   KCEHSAWIDFNLMPVBQTOJRXUG
S. Key:   vmrdtonhilxwagfsecjkbupq
Cipher 1: oowaoijhbhjxcdbrrccbsjdo
Cipher 2: jwoiyaljrtjccmpgdtpxalcr

P. Key:   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX
S. Key:   osmirlqdhkvwaxjgebtcpfnu
Cipher 1: irobwhoahboxcjcdrsocdbjj
Cipher 2: agwrotrijxjccjpmdaytcpll
```

The first line on the blackboard is a substitution key. After applying the substitution:

```
Cipher:  osmirlqdhkvwaxjgebtcpfnu
Plain:   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX

irobwhoahboxcjcdrsocdbjjagwrotrijxjccjpmdaytcpll
DEARLIAMIRANTOTHEBATHROOMPLEASEDONOTTOUCHMYSTUFF
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer yet, but I couldn't just keep on posting all my observations in comments so I will do it here.

> The first line have 1 of each of the 24 letters which seems to indicate another level of permutation or something. I have yet to find out how to use it but it will be important to figure out if the first level of permutation must be used on it before it is usable.
>  I also noticed that there is a y in the message, which can be a hint toward something or simply meant to be left as a y.
>
>  I tried many many things which all let to pure giberrish.
>  First, since the first line has 24 different letters, and the message has 25(with the y), I assumed that the whole cube puzzle was meant to decode the first line, and then we could use the first line to solve the message, but it has not worked.

Comment: Your first observation is very important, especially given that I tried to hint  (via proximity) that that first line might be used with the alphabet string above the board.

Answer (score 1):

Now that the rubik cube has been solved, I tried various permutaions (spoilers have some weird interaction with other formatting, but this is not the solution yet)

> sorting the three lines:
>  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx  <= same as on the cube but permuted differently
>  abbbcccddhhijjjoooorrswx  <= not all letters present, many duplicates but not enough vowels
>  aacccdgijjjllmopprrttwxy

_

> writing them on the cube in the solved snakified order:
>
> ```
>   vm        oo        jw  
>   dr        aw        io  
> tonhil    oijhbh    yaljrt  
> sfgawx    rbdcxj    gpmccj  
>   ec        rc        dt  
>   kj        bc        xp  
>   bu        sj        al  
>   qp        od        rc
> ```
>
> ...then rotating the cube to the original position
>
> ```
> oximdlprhjaksgfvebctqwun
> ijboahdwhccbrdborscooxjj
> ajrwitcojpcxgmpjdatyrcll
>
>   ox        ij        aj
>   mi        ob        wr
> dlprhj    ahdwhc    itcojp
> vfgska    obdrbc    jpmgxc
>   eb        rs        da
>   tc        oc        yt
>   qw        ox        rc
>   nu        jj        ll
> ```
>
> writing them on the unsolved cube then solving it
>
> ```
> sdhtkvqiromuxgfaejlwcpnb
> rahoboobwiojjdbcrchxcdjs
> gijyxjrroawljmpcdptctcla   
>
>   sd        ra        gi
>   th        oh        yj
> kvqiro    boobwi    xjrroa
> afgxum    cbdjjo    cpmjlw
>   ej        rc        dp
>   wl        xh        ct
>   cp        cd        tc
>   bn        sj        al
> ```
>
> treating the first line as a cube permutation and [un-]solving the other two lines
>
> ```
> catidpmjrpxtwlacrogyljcj
> cscarbdhbcbhojidowrojoxj
>
>   ca        cs
>   it        ac
> dpmjrp    rbdhbc
> calwtx    dijohb
>   ro        ow
>   yg        or
>   lj        jo
>   jc        jx
>
> jccabbdhbxodojicowhjosrr
> lctixpmjrcrcjlapyotjwagd
>
>   jc        lc
>   ac        it
> bbdhbx    xpmjrc
> cijodo    paljcr
>   ow        yo
>   jh        jt
>   os        wa
>   rr        dg
> ```

none of this seems to produce any meaningful words even if reading in any direction on the surface of the cube

> if the second and third line are both part of the message, there must be an additonal step to replace the letters and not simply permute them.
>  There is not enough data for frequency analysis, but roughly mapping the top 6 "cjoradb" to the most frequent letters "etaoins" makes some of the messages almost readable (with phrases like "awaiting you at the temple" scattered around if you squint). Mapping the alphabet, first line and cube to each other, however, keeps it unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

My immediate thought is

> an XOR cipher where the first line is the key, the second and third line XOR to each other, and give the plain-text out.

But it just gives you nonsense.

ALL of which are system characters. ([Used this to decode this](http://www.systutorials.com/4670/ascii-table-and-ascii-code/))

```
19 02  05  05  1b  06  04  00  0b 04  12 0f 02  03  04  01  17  00  09 09 11  1f 14 1e
EM STX ENQ ENQ ESC ACK EOT NUL VT EOT FF SI STX ETX EOT SOH ETB NUL HT HT DC1 US SO RS
```

Which is nonsense, because you have a text that never ends (1st 02), no SOT's for the 3 EOT's, and the device turns on AFTER a bunch of instructions, which leads me to believe the whole sequence of bytes before that DC1 instruction (190205051b0604000b04120f0203040117000909) is a start up sequence.

if you say the first line is needed to encode the message, then it must be a Vigenere or Variant Beaufort, but they don't do a thing.